# connecting to Postgres with Perl

Tags: perl, postgresql

I have installed Postgres in my machine, and I'm trying to connect to it using `Perl`.

```
$database = "heatmap";
$user = "postgres";
$password = "<password>";

#connect to Postgres database
my $db = DBI->connect(
        "DBI:Pg:database=$db;",
        $user,
        $password
) or die "Can't Connect to database: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
DBI connect('database=;','postgres',...) failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "souzamor" at C:/Users/souzamor/workspace/Parser/Parser.pl line 13.
Can't Connect to database: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "souzamor"
```

`souzamor` is my Windows username. However, I'm trying to connect as `postgres`. I went ahead and created an user called `souzamor` in Postgres, but I got:

```
DBI connect('database=;','souzamor',...) failed: FATAL:  database "user='souzamor'" does not exist at C:/Users/souzamor/workspace/Parser/Parser.pl line 13.
Can't Connect to database: FATAL:  database "user='souzamor'" does not exist
```

I'm totally new with Postgres. Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean

```
my $db = DBI->connect(
        "DBI:Pg:database=$database",
```

instead of

```
my $db = DBI->connect(
        "DBI:Pg:database=$db;",
```

*Edit*

According to [this](http://search.cpan.org/~rudy/DBD-Pg/Pg.pm), it should be:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:Pg:dbname=$database", $user, $password);
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to connect to mysql you said in comment

```
#connect to MySQL database
my $db = DBI->connect(
        "DBI:Pg:database=$db;",
        $user,
        $password
```

but somehow why you use DBI::Pg << instead using module DBI::mysql ?

*Pg - PostgreSQL

*correct me if my answer is wrong*

Comment: Corrected! Plx check it again